# MySQL Error: 1067

Tags: mysql

When I try t start MySQL server service it is giving an error:

"Could not start the MySQL server in local computer
 Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly"

I need to fix the problem without having to uninstall the MySQL server. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This thread](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,11388,11388#msg-11388) has several solutions to the problem that you mentioned. It may be the file path or incorrectly located my.ini. Please go through the suggested solutions to see which one fits your need. [This suggestion](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,11388,16051#msg-16051) seems most hopeful.

Try

```
mysqld --remove MySql
```

Then

```
mysqld --install <service name> --defaults-file={full path of "my.ini" file}
```

Comment: I saw it. But still cant figure out what the problem is. So can you list me some troubleshooting methods here